# Np.where(x followed by y)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with a column with blocks of 1 (for instance)
[(see screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhtNF.png)

I would like to create another column which signals True only at the beginning (first cell) and end (last cell) of each block. So that when 0 is followed by 1 and 1 is followed by 0 it is true.

For instance in a column with values `[0,1,1,1,1,0]` I'm looking to get another column like this : `[0,1,0,0,1,0]`.

I figured I could use np.where, but I have no idea how to implement the corresponding conditions. I tried this :
`df['output'] = np.where(df['signal'].rolling(2).mean() == 0.5, 1, 0)`
It works well to signal the first cell, but the signal in the output column for the last cell is shifted compared to the signal column.

Could you please help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO Matt. I voted to close because this site is not for questions of the type "I want to do x, but have no idea how".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `where` is not an iterator; it's a selector.  It's only as useful as the 3 arguments (arrays, series, or frames).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the one-line solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], columns=['signal'])

# Solution
df['output'] = np.where((df['signal'].diff().eq(1)) | (df['signal'].diff().shift(-1) == -1), True, False)
```

Comment: Thanks but that gives me the same problem! I also reached the same result with df['output'] = np.where(df['signal'].rolling(2).mean() == 0.5, 1, 0), it works well to signal the first cell, but the signal in the output column for the last cell is shifted compared to the signal column.

Comment: Could you provide us the expected output in your questioin? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear, for instance in a column with values  [0,1,1,1,1,0] I'm looking to get another column like this : [0,1,0,0,1,0]

Comment: I've modified the answer, let's try!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much quantscientist !

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `np.abs` and `np.diff`, and cast the result to a boolean array

So, for example, if your sequence is `x = [0,0,0,1,1,0,0]`

```py
diffs = np.diff(x) # has value [0,0,-1,0,1,0]
abs_diffs = np.abs(diffs) # has value [0,0,1,0,1,0]
boolean_array = abs_diffs == 1 # [False, False, True, False, True, False]
```

Note that this array has a length which is one less than your original array, you need to decide what your sequences mean for the first/last element in your list